# Typescript type to filter keys of type string[]

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type:

```
interface Filter<P extends object> {
  label: string;
  options: FilterOption[];
  key: StringArrayKeyOf<P>;
}
```

Where `StringArrayKeyOf` is:

```
type StringArrayKeyOf<T extends object> = Exclude<{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string[] ? K : never; }[keyof T], undefined>;
```

When I try to use it like:

```
const stateFilters: Filter<GiftOrderHistoryParams> = {
  label: '상태',
  options: stateOptions,
  key: 'state',
};
```

Where `GiftOrderHistoryParams` is of type:

```
interface GiftOrderHistoryParams {
  ...
  state?: string[];
}
```

I get an error on the `key` property:

> Type string is not assignable to type never

The type of `key` should be a string that indexes type `P` where the value is of a `string[]`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. The issue was that `StringArrayKeyOf` did not account for optional properties.

The updated version works:

```
type StringArrayKeyOf<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string[] | undefined ? K : never;
}[keyof T];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more straightforward, imperative-like version for your situation.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

```js
type Test<T extends object> = keyof T extends infer I // for each key I,
  ? I extends keyof T // ensure I is assignable to keyof T,
    ? T[I] extends string[] | undefined // if T[I] is string[] | undefined,
      ? I // include the key in the resulting type
      : never
    : never
  : never;
```

This method does not require `Exclude<..., undefined>`.